# recognize and replace links in yahoo pipes with regex

Tags: regex, replace, find, pipe, yahoo

would there be a formula to recognize any link out of rss feeds and replace them with a fix value with regex in yahoo pipes?

Answer (score 1):

Sure! there is a pipe for this!

Just have a quick look up on Autodiscovery mode
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=sources#FeedAutoDiscovery

By looking inside this module you have a regex treatment to recognise any other url in the page